# Determine the following property

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For an integer $k \geq 3$, determine all sets $A=\{a1,...,a_k\}$ of  positive integers that have the following property: Whenever h,i,j are distinct then each of $a_h,a_i,a_j$ divides $a_h+a_i+a_j$.

Comment: Must the $k$ positive integers be distinct?

Comment: Originally written as "Whenever $\{a,b,c\}\subset A,$ then each of $a,b,c$ divides $ a+b+c.$"  Which allowed $a=b $, giving $\forall a,c \in A\;(a|c)$

Answer (score 1):

let $a_1\leq a_2\leq\dots \leq a_k$ be the $k$ positive integers. Then we have that $a_i+a_j$ is a multiple of $a_k$ for $1\leq i<j<k$. This means $a_i\equiv-a_j$ for all $1\leq i<j<k$.

If $k>3$ this implies $a_1=a_2=a_3\dots=a_{k-1}$.(To see this notice $a_2=a_3\dots =a_{k-1}$, because they are all congruent to $-a_1\bmod a_k$, since $a_k$ is the largest one the equality follows, analogously $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_{k-2}$ because they are all congruent to $-a_{k-1}\bmod a_k$).

So our set consists of an integer $a$, repeated $k-1$ times and an integer $b\geq a$ that appears once. It is easy to see that $b$ must be a multiple of $a$. So $b=am$, and $am$ must divide $a+a+am$, so $m|(m+2)$, meaning $b=a$ or $b=2a$.

If $k=3$ then there are more options, let the numbers be $x\leq y\leq z$. Suppose $x$ and $y$ have already been selected, then we must have that $z$ is a divisor of $x+y$, now, notice $x+y\leq 2y$ (with equality only if $x=y$, So if $x$ is not $x+y$ (but a proper divisor) then $z=y=x$.

In the other case the set is $x,y,x+y$, so now all that remains is to see for which values of $x,y$ we have that $x$ and $y$ divide $2(x+y)$. Clearly this is equivalent to asking $x$ to divide $x+2y$ and $y$ to divide $x+2y$, which again, is equivalent to asking $x$ divides $2y$ and $y$ divides $2x$. So $x=y$ or $2x=y$.

From here the solutions are:

$\{x,2x,3x\}$

$\{x,x,x\}$

$\{x,x,2x\}$

Comment: I think your second paragraph should be revised for clarity.If $ k>3 $ and if  $h,i,j$  are distinct and less than $ k$  then  (modulo  $a_k$) we have $a_h\equiv -a_i\equiv -(-a_j) \to a_h\equiv  a_j$,  but we also have  $a_h\equiv -a_j.$  So $2 a_j\equiv 0$ and $a_i\equiv  -a_j.$  Since $a_k$ is the maximal member, this implies that $\{a_i :i<k\}$ is either $\{a_k\}$ or $ \{a_k/2\}$.

Comment: @user254665 I see your point, but my approach i different.

Comment: It goes as follows: $a_2\equiv a_3\equiv a_2\dots \equiv a_{k-1}$. Why? Because they are all congruent to $-a_1$. Since they are all congruent between each other $\bmod a_k$ and $a_k$ is the maximal element we conclude $a_2=a_3=a_3\dots= a_{k-1}$.

Comment: Using the same argument we get $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_{k-2}$

Comment: Oh yeah, I had made some typos, I think it is ok now.

Comment: The fact that $ k-2$  numbers  $(k>3)$ not exceeding $a_k$ are congruent to each other mod $a_k$ is insufficient to imply they are all equal. We also need the fact that they are pairwise congruent to the negatives of each other.

Comment: @user254665 if they are congruent then their negatives are also congruent, clearly if $a\equiv b \bmod a_k$ and $a,b\in\{1,2,3\dots a_k\}$ then $a=b$.